# Knockout Validation onlyif object no function and pattern validation

Tags: validation, if-statement, design-patterns, knockout.js, required

I want to the priceMax was required, when title is empty.

I have code

```
self.searchParameters = {
    title: ko.observable().extend({
      refreshCountOffers: 500
    }),
    priceMax: ko.observable().extend({
      required: {
        onlyIf: function() {
          return  title==null;
        }
      },
      refreshCountOffers: 500
    })
  };
```

,but I get error 'title is not defined'.

How to disable option, which show error for pattern validation, when user input first letter?

```
postCode: ko.observable().extend({
  required: true,
  pattern: {
    message: 'Post code is not valid',
    params: '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}'
  },
  refreshCountOffers: 500
})
```

my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/llukaszz92/ybamy0du/)

Comment: I think you have asked 2 questions here.  Unless they are related (and I do not believe that they are) then you should ask them in separate questions

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with the `onlyIf` check:

1. you need to qualify the `title` property
2. `title` is observable so you need to access the value

The code below resolves both:

```
onlyIf: function() {
    return self.searchParameters.title();
}
```

Comment: Thank, but I get error "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" https://jsfiddle.net/llukaszz92/ybamy0du/3/

Comment: Ah, this is because `self.searchParameters` has not been assigned when `onlyIf` is first invoked.  In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybamy0du/4/) I have pulled the construction of `searchParameters` out into separate statements so that `onlyIf` can access the variable